# Is it possible to bind a WPF Event to MVVM ViewModel command?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a xaml window and on the StateChanged event of the window I have to execute a piece of code. I have to follow MVVM. I binded the StateChanged property to an ICommand? It doesn't work.

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="DummyApp"
x:Name="Window"
Title="Dummy App"
Width="{Binding WindowWidth,Mode=OneWayToSource}" Height="{Binding WindowHeight}" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" Icon="Logo.png" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"  WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="{Binding CurrentWindowState, Mode=TwoWay}"
ShowInTaskbar="{Binding ShowInTaskBar, Mode=TwoWay}" StateChanged="{Binding IsMinimized}">
```

This is my viewmodel.

```
public ICommand IsMinimized
    {
        get
        {
            if (_IsMinimized == null)
            {
                _IsMinimized = new RelayCommand(param => this.OnMinimized(), null);
            }
            return _IsMinimized;
        }
    }

    private void OnMinimized()
    {
        //do something here
    }
```

Is there anyother way to do this?

Comment: *I bound the `Window.StateChanged` Event to an `ICommand` and it didn't work?*... Really? Why was that? Perhaps because an `ICommand` is *not* an event?

Comment: @RohitVats, how did you manage to close this question as a duplicate *of a question that has no accepted answer*? I didn't think that we could do that.

Comment: Ok this won't work. But is there any other way to do this? I did find a way to bind a RoutedEvent to a command from here [Binding RoutedEvent to Command](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/09/hooking-up-commands-to-events-in-wpf.html) But StateChanged is not a RoutedEvent? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: *Ok this won't work*... why not? It does for everyone else? Alternatively, just handle the `Window.StateChanged` Event in the code behind and in the handler, simply execute your `ICommand`: `var viewModel = (SomeDataType)DataContext; viewModel.YourCommand.Execute(params);`

Comment: @Sheridan - Ok. I will reopen the question but most voted answer definitely work. Not sure how OP using it.

Comment: @user1890098 - Can you edit the question with what have you tried and it doesn't work?

Comment: @RohitVats, I wasn't requesting that you re-open the question... as I said, I just didn't think that it was possible for users to link to a duplicate question if it had no accepted answer. I guess I must be mistaken.

Comment: @Sheridan - No. its possible to mark duplicate of question if it has any answers.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that... it's good to know. However, this question author clearly has no interest in implementing any of these (or the previously linked) solutions, so perhaps it would be better to re-close this question.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the all the help. But I ended up binding WindowState to a property and handled the code there.

```
public WindowState CurrentWindowState
    {
        get { return _currentWindowState; }
        set
        {
            _currentWindowState = value;
            if (_currentWindowState == WindowState.Minimized)  //any other clause here
            {
               //do something here
            }
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentWindowState");
        }
    }
```

Comment: NotifyPropertyChanged is only needed, if you want to change CurrentWindowState from within your code and want to notify the UI about it, so that you are able to minimize/maximize/... your window from your viewmodel

Comment: to make it better, change your setter to
`if (_currentWindowState != value) { _currentWindowState = value; if (_currentWindowState == WindowState.Minimized) { ... } ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can bind events to your model, but you need help.
You need to use functions from the [System.Windows.Interactivity Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity(v=expression.40).aspx) and include a [MVVM Light](http://www.mvvmlight.net/) (there might be other MVVM libraries that have that feature but i use MVVM Light).

Include the following namespaces to your window

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras"
```

and bind your events like

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="StateChanged">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding StateChangedCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

HTH

Comment: Caliburn lets you do it with messages (and a litle less code).